# TensorFlow equivalent of PyTorch's transforms.Normalize()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to inference a TFLite model that was originally built in PyTorch. I have been following along the lines of the [PyTorch implementation](https://github.com/leoxiaobin/deep-high-resolution-net.pytorch/blob/1ee551d619641268c2ebd80134101db6e962f45f/demo/inference.py#L93) and have to preprocess images along the RGB channels. I found the closest TensorFlow equivalent of `transforms.Normalize()` to be `tf.image.per_image_standardization()` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization)). Although this is a pretty good match, `tf.image.per_image_standardization()` does this by taking mean and std across the channels and applies it to them. Here's their full implementation from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py)

```py
def per_image_standardization(image):
  """Linearly scales `image` to have zero mean and unit norm.
  This op computes `(x - mean) / adjusted_stddev`, where `mean` is the average
  of all values in image, and
  `adjusted_stddev = max(stddev, 1.0/sqrt(image.NumElements()))`.
  `stddev` is the standard deviation of all values in `image`. It is capped
  away from zero to protect against division by 0 when handling uniform images.
  Args:
    image: 3-D tensor of shape `[height, width, channels]`.
  Returns:
    The standardized image with same shape as `image`.
  Raises:
    ValueError: if the shape of 'image' is incompatible with this function.
  """
  image = ops.convert_to_tensor(image, name='image')
  _Check3DImage(image, require_static=False)
  num_pixels = math_ops.reduce_prod(array_ops.shape(image))

  image = math_ops.cast(image, dtype=dtypes.float32)
  image_mean = math_ops.reduce_mean(image)

  variance = (math_ops.reduce_mean(math_ops.square(image)) -
              math_ops.square(image_mean))
  variance = gen_nn_ops.relu(variance)
  stddev = math_ops.sqrt(variance)

  # Apply a minimum normalization that protects us against uniform images.
  min_stddev = math_ops.rsqrt(math_ops.cast(num_pixels, dtypes.float32))
  pixel_value_scale = math_ops.maximum(stddev, min_stddev)
  pixel_value_offset = image_mean

  image = math_ops.subtract(image, pixel_value_offset)
  image = math_ops.div(image, pixel_value_scale)
  return image
```

whereas PyTorch's `transforms.Normalize()` allows us to mention the mean and std to be applied across each channel like below.

```py
# transformation
    pose_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])
```

What would be a way to get this functionality in TensorFlow 2.x?

**Edit:**
I created a quick botch that seems to solve this by defining a function as such:

```py
def normalize_image(image, mean, std):
    for channel in range(3):
        image[:,:,channel] = (image[:,:,channel] - mean[channel])/std[channel]
    
    return image
```

I'm not sure how efficient this is but seems to get the job done. I still have to convert the output to a tensor before inputing to the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround that you mentioned seems ok. But using `for...loop` to compute normalization to **each RGB** channel for a **single image** can be a bit problematic when you deal with a large dataset in the data pipeline (`generator` or `tf.data`). But it's ok anyway. Here is the demonstration of your approach, and later we will provide two possible alternatives that might work for you easily.

```
from PIL import Image 
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, subplot, title, hist

# load image (RGB)
img = Image.open('/content/9.jpg')

def normalize_image(image, mean, std):
    for channel in range(3):
        image[:,:,channel] = (image[:,:,channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]
    return image

OP_approach = normalize_image(np.array(img) / 255.0, 
                            mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                            std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

Now, let's observe the transform properties afterward.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(OP_approach); title(f'Normalized Image \n min-px: \
    {OP_approach.min()} \n max-pix: {OP_approach.max()}')
subplot(122); hist(OP_approach.ravel(), bins=50, density=True); \ 
                                    title('Histogram - pixel distribution')
```

[image]

The range of minimum and maximum pixel after normalization are (`-2.1179039301310043`, `2.6399999999999997`) respectively.

### Option 2

We can use the [**tf. keras...Normalization**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Normalization) preprocessing layer to do the same. It takes two important arguments which are `mean` and, `variance` (square of the `std`).

```
from tensorflow.keras.experimental.preprocessing import Normalization

input_data = np.array(img)/255
layer = Normalization(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                      variance=[np.square(0.299), 
                                np.square(0.224), 
                                np.square(0.225)])

plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(layer(input_data).numpy()); title(f'Normalized Image \n min-px: \
   {layer(input_data).numpy().min()} \n max-pix: {layer(input_data).numpy().max()}')
subplot(122); hist(layer(input_data).numpy().ravel(), bins=50, density=True);\
   title('Histogram - pixel distribution')
```

[image]

The range of minimum and maximum pixel after normalization are (`-2.0357144`, `2.64`) respectively.

### Option 3

This is more like subtracting the average `mean` and divide by the average `std`.

```
norm_img = ((tf.cast(np.array(img), tf.float32) / 255.0) - 0.449) / 0.226

plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(norm_img.numpy()); title(f'Normalized Image \n min-px: \
{norm_img.numpy().min()} \n max-pix: {norm_img.numpy().max()}')
subplot(122); hist(norm_img.numpy().ravel(), bins=50, density=True); \
title('Histogram - pixel distribution')
```

[image]

The range of minimum and maximum pixel after normalization are (`-1.9867257`, `2.4380531`) respectively. Lastly, if we compare to the `pytorch` way, there is not that much difference among these approaches.

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform_norm = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                            std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])
norm_pt = transform_norm(img)

plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(np.array(norm_pt).transpose(1, 2, 0));\
  title(f'Normalized Image \n min-px: \
  {np.array(norm_pt).min()} \n max-pix: {np.array(norm_pt).max()}')
subplot(122); hist(np.array(norm_pt).ravel(), bins=50, density=True); \
  title('Histogram - pixel distribution')
```

[image]

The range of minimum and maximum pixel after normalization are (`-2.117904`, `2.64`) respectively.