# Tensorflow version of Pytorch Transforms

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I have the following code that I use to prepare images before performing inference in a [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) model:

```
def image_loader(transform, image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    #transform
    image = transform(image).float()
    image = torch.tensor(image)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    return image

data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
```

I've converted the model into a Tensorflow model, however, I'm unsure how I would do similar transformations to images before inference since there doesn't seem to be a [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) or [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) equivalent. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some pointer, in [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) you have

```
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image 
import torch 

def image_loader(transform, image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
    image = transform(image).float()
    image = torch.tensor(image)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    return image

data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# check: visualize 
i = image_loader(data_transforms, '/content/1.png')
i.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(np.array(i[0]).transpose(1, 2, 0));
```

And in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), you can achieve this as follows

```
def transform(image, mean, std):
    for channel in range(3):
        image[:, :, channel] = (image[:, :, channel] - mean[channel]) \
            / std[channel]
    return image


def image_loader(image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
    image = transform(np.array(image) / 255, mean=[0.485, 0.456,
                      0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image

# check: visualize 
i = image_loader('/content/1.png')
i.shape 

plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
subplot(121); imshow(i[0]);
```

**This should output the same.** Note, in the second case, we define the `transform` function, from another OP, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67484253/9215780), it's fine, however, you can also check [tf. keras...Normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Normalization), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67484253/9215780) for details.